How can I define a shared route parameter in Blazor to automatically use on multiple pages
I have a Blazor Web App (.Net8) with a lot of pages.
Is there a way to define a shared route parameter without having to set it manually for every page? All pages where I want to add this route parameter use render mode Interactive Server.
Suppose I have 3 separate components with different routes:
@page "/home"
@page "/faq"
@page "/contact"

Now for example I want to add some localization by using a route parameter. I could set this manually on every single page:
@page "/{culture}/home"
@page "/{culture}/faq"
@page "/{culture}/contact"

But I would prefer a global solution where some route parameters are automatically defined for every page. If I want to add another route parameter later on, I can set it in one place instead of manually on every page component.

You could look at attribute-based routing.
Define a lookup class as follows:
public static class UrlLookup
{
    private const string RoutePrefix = "/{culture}";
    
    public const string Home = $"{RoutePrefix}/home";
    public const string Faq = $"{RoutePrefix}/faq";
    public const string Contact = $"{RoutePrefix}/contact";
}

And then using your FAQ component as an example, replace this:
@page "/faq"

With this:
@attribute [Route(UrlLookup.Faq)]

The advantage of this approach is that you keep your URLs declared in only one place. This is also very useful when linking to other components (e.g. navigation menus).
E.g.
<a href="@UrlLookup.Faq">FAQ</a>


This would certainly have the advantage of being centralized, but I still would have to change every url manually since the attribute requires a const.

I see what you mean. I have modified the above to allow for a common route prefix which I think achieves what you want.

Ok, great. I am going to use this approach. I guess for even more complex scenarios I would have to look into writing a custom RouteManager.

With this approach you will need a matching RouteParameter for every parameter in the prefix. I think it is best to inherit all page components from a custom base component where the route parameters are defined. Maybe include that in your answer?
